# How to fix 'arrStud was not declared in this scope' error in C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a program where it'll display the student records in 4 columns(ID, first name, last name, and GPA), sort their records in ascending order, and reset each of their GPA to 0.0 from the sorted student records.

The student records are stored in a text file I called "StudentInfo.txt"

```
123456789   John    Johnson    3.5
512434990   Mary    Jackson    3.9
342432444   Peter   Young      2.3
470068625   Jim     Lee        2.9
234324324   Tammy   Gaddis     3.1
121219000   Ester   Schwab     2.7
```

The thing I'm having trouble with is declaring a structure array before `ifstream inputFile`. An error message displaying `"arrStud was not declared in this scope"` in lines 42, 53, and 68.

I have tried to implement `studentInfo **arrStud[SIZE]` and `studentInfo *arrStud[SIZE]` but it didn't work and another pile of errors occurred.

If anyone can help me out on how to fix this, I would appreciate it!

My Current Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct studentInfo
{
    int ID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    double GPA;
};

const int SIZE = 100;
void display(/*parameter*/,int);
void resetGPA(studentInfo **, int);
void sortStud(studentInfo **, int);

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int ID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    double GPA;

    // Declare arrStud here...

    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("StudentInfo.txt");
    if (inputFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ID:" << setw(15) << "Name:" << setw(14) << "GPA:" << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;

        while(!inputFile.eof())
        {
            inputFile >> ID >> firstName >> lastName >> GPA;
            arrStud[counter] = new studentInfo;

            arrStud[counter]->ID = ID;
            arrStud[counter]->firstName = firstName;
            arrStud[counter]->lastName = lastName;
            arrStud[counter]->GPA = GPA;

            counter++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        cout << i << arrStud[i]->ID
             << setw(8) << arrStud[i]->firstName
             << setw(10) << arrStud[i]->lastName
             << setw(8) << arrStud[i]->GPA
             << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        inputFile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "File cannot be opened.";
        inputFile.close();


    display(arrStud, counter);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sorting Students by ID..." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    sortStud(arrStud, ID);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Resetting GPA Data..." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    resetGPA(arrStud, GPA);
}

void display()
{

}

void resetGPA(studentInfo** students, int numStu)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < numStu; i++)
    {
        students[i]->GPA = 0.0;
    }

}

void sortStud(studentInfo** students, int numStu)
{
    int lowestIDIndex; //holds the index in the array students of the student with the lowest ID

    for (int i = 0; i < numStu; i ++)
    {
        lowestIDIndex = i; //always start with lowest ID being first student

        for (int j = i; j < numStu; j++) //j is equal to i so that you don't search the already sorted elements, which are less than i
        {
            if (students[j]->ID < students[lowestIDIndex]->ID) //search for the lowest ID
            {
                lowestIDIndex = j; //keep track of the lowest ID
            }
        }
            //switch the lowest element with the front-most element
            studentInfo* tempStuPtr = students[i];
            students[i] = students[lowestIDIndex];
            students[lowestIDIndex] = tempStuPtr;
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
ID:          Name:          GPA:
-----------------------------------
123456789    John   Johnson     3.5
512434990    Mary   Jackson     3.9
342432444   Peter     Young     2.3
470068625     Jim       Lee     2.9
234324324   Tammy    Gaddis     3.1
121219000   Ester    Schwab     2.7
-----------------------------------


Sorting Students by ID...

ID:          Name:          GPA:
-----------------------------------
512434990    Mary   Jackson     3.9
123456789    John   Johnson     3.5
234324324   Tammy    Gaddis     3.1
470068625     Jim       Lee     2.9
121219000   Ester    Schwab     2.7
342432444   Peter     Young     2.3
-----------------------------------


Resetting GPA Data...

ID:          Name:          GPA:
-----------------------------------
512434990    Mary   Jackson     0.0
123456789    John   Johnson     0.0
234324324   Tammy    Gaddis     0.0
470068625     Jim       Lee     0.0
121219000   Ester    Schwab     0.0
342432444   Peter     Young     0.0
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code is `arrStud` declared! You need something like this, near the top of your `main()` function (or you can put it as a global variable, say immediately before the definition of `main`):

```
studentInfo* arrStd[SIZE];
```

And then, at (or near) the end of your `main`, you need to free the memory created with the `new` calls:

```
for (int c = 0; c < counter; ++c) delete arrStud[c];
```

You will also need to correct your declaration and definition for the `display` function, like so:

```
void display(studentInfo**, int);

void display(studentInfo** students, int numStu)
{
    // Do something here, I guess!
}
```

Comment: There are a number of other errors in your code! These will become clear if you enable compiler warnings for your next build.